# Searching applicants by email through the Queue Class (listnode) fromt he GUI of the program

Tags: java, list, swing, jtextfield

I have a program for my homework where we add/edit/remove/allocate students who have applied to uni/college with the contact details and ucas points. One of their contact details involves their email.

Basically I want to find an applicant I want to edit by email. I don't have much knowledge of list-nodes but I think I got it right, but it isn't working.

I've tried this with int search methods and it seems to work fine however with strings not so much.

This is from the `AppGUI`

```
if(e.getSource() == btnFind)
        {
            ApplicantQueue editApplicant = new ApplicantQueue();

            String findEmail = txtFind.getText();
            editApplicant.search(findEmail);
            taEditDelteDisplay.setText(editApplicant.display());
    if(editApplicant.getFront().getAppDetails().getEmail() == findEmail)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NOTICE, \nQualifications & UCAS Points have been cleared!\n you must re-enter this information!",  "INFO", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
    if(editApplicant.getFront().getAppDetails().getEmail() == null)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NONE FOUND, \nEmail not found.",   "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
```

This is from the queue class(listnodes)

```
public DegreeApp search(String email)
        {
            ListNode current = front;
while(current != null && current.getAppDetails().getEmail().equals(email) != false)
            {
                current = current.getLink();
            }
            if(current != null)
                return current.getAppDetails();
            else
            return null;// dunno about this part so put it to null
        }
        //original int method
        /*public int search(int reqNo)
        {
            int pos = 1;
            ListNode current = front;
            while(current != null && current.getAppDetails().getPriority() != reqNo)
            {
                current = current.getLink();
                pos++;
            }
            if(current != null)
                return pos;
            else
                return -1;
        }*/
```

When they proper applicant is found by email, I want to be able to edit that given applicant, I have fully coded that part yet as I wanted to get the search working first, as you can see I've already made popups for when they're either found or that none exist.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello Sean. Your question is too broad/vague. Can you please edit your question and code to make it clearer what you are seeking help with?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can easier understand, where is your problem and provide a solution that is suitable for your case. Please don't post your complete code, but rather create a short runnable class, that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice about the question lads. As you can tell im only starting my (hopefully career) path in programming this past year. Ill take all the advice i can get and my next question might be better. (I somehow fixed the issue, thanks btw)